# Making a procedural mask for a specific parts of a mesh

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, masking

My question is similar to this: [How to make a procedural hair strand texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32404/how-to-make-a-procedural-hair-strand-texture)!
I textured some body parts of my model using images (.jpgs) as masks. Now I want all of them to be exchanged to procedural ones.
For example I succeed to make a procedural mask for an eye (as pictured below).
[image]

Now I wonder how to do the same trick on my jaw mesh. I want a mask to appear only on the teeth tips (the dark parts of the teeth pictured below), where transparent material would be applied. Is it possible, assuming that this is one solid mesh without any loose parts?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pointiness feature may be able to do what you are looking for.  You can bring the results into visual range by using a Color Ramp node.

[image]